# How would you group timestamps by chunks of given duration?

Tags: python, grouping

Say that you have a sorted list of n timestamps (Python `datetime` objects). How would you yield a list of tuples of the form `(t, count)`, where `t` is a `datetime` object and `count` is the number of elements in the list at most `x` minutes from `t`?

For example, given the dates (strings, for brevity; in reality `datetime` objects):

```
timestamps = ["13:00", "13:01", "13:03", "13:04", "13:05", "13:06", "13:09"]
```

if `x` is two minutes, then yield

```
[("13:00", 2), ("13:03":3), ("13:06":1), ("13:09", 1)]]
```

What I'm trying to do is make a coarser list of hits on a resource, and the only data I have is the access time of every hit (the granularization is to the millisecond, and I'd like it granular to the minute, or ten minutes)

I would post my attempts, but I'm ashamed...

Edit: This is what I have so far... testing to see if it works...

```
def group_timestamps(timestamps, chunksize=10):
    """Groups a list of timestamps in chunks of ``chunksize`` minutes"""
    cs = timedelta(minutes=chunksize)

    if not timestamps:
        return []

    t0 = timestamps[0]
    count = 1
    chunks = []

    for ts in timestamps:
        if (ts - t0) <= cs:
            count += 1
        else:
            chunks.append((t0, count))
            t0 = ts
            count = 1
    return chunks
```

Comment: That's about the answer I've given. You have forgotten to add the last chunk to the list of chunks. This must be done outside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the last tuple!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
current = timestamps[0]
count = 0
res = []
for t in timestamps:
    if (t - current) <=  timedelta(minutes= 2): 
         count = count + 1
    else:
         res.append((current,count))
         current = t
         count = 1
res.append(current,count) #add last tuple
```

Following your example:

```
timestamps = [datetime(hours=13,minutes=00), datetime(hours=13,minutes=01), datetime(hours=13,minutes=03), datetime(hours=13,minutes=04), datetime(hours=13,minutes=05), datetime(hours=13,minutes=06), datetime(hours=13,minutes=09)]

res = [(datetime(hours=13,minutes=00),2),(datetime(hours=13,minutes=03),3),(datetime(hours=13,minutes=06),1),(datetime(hours=13,minutes=09),1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version of a solution:

```
from datetime import datetime

# SAMPLE TIMESTAMP DATA
timestamps = []
timestamps.append(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1338777480))
timestamps.append(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1338777580))
timestamps.append(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1338777610))
timestamps.append(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1338777680))
timestamps.append(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1338777780))
timestamps.append(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1338777980))
timestamps.append(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1338778180))
timestamps.append(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1338778230))
timestamps.append(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1338778480))

MIN_THRSH = 2  # Range in minutes within to chunk data.

def chunk_time(timestamp_list):
    chunk_list = []
    current_chunk_idx = None
    for i, dt in enumerate(timestamp_list):
        if (i == 0 or
            ((dt - timestamp_list[current_chunk_idx]).seconds / 60) > MIN_THRSH):
            chunk_list.append([dt.strftime('%H:%M'), 1])
            current_chunk_idx = i
        else:
            chunk_list[-1][1] += 1
    return chunk_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for t in timestamps:
        print t.strftime('%H:%M')
    print chunk_time(timestamps)
```

Output:

```
02:38
02:39
02:40
02:41
02:43
02:46
02:49
02:50
02:54
[['02:38', 3], ['02:41', 2], ['02:46', 1], ['02:49', 2], ['02:54', 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm digesting it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need counts, you can simply use a histogram on unix timestamps. e.g. `numpy.histogram`.